# How to copy executable file of ExePackage to the target machine's specified directory using Wix Burn?

Tags: variables, wix, built-in, burn, payload

In my wix bootstrapper project I have two exe packages (for 32 and 64 bit) and msi package.I'd like to install one of exe packages and then install msi. But I also need the executables of both exe packages to be copied to the target directory, designed in msi. The problem is that if I install them like other files in msi:

```
    <Component Id="cmp9A1327054E32" Directory="dir088" Guid="GUID">
        <File Id="filA60" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.PathToFile)\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" />
    </Component>
```

this would double the size of my bundle (2 executables for exe packages and 2 for msi).
 So my question is **"How can I use the same .exe files for both installing exe packages and just copying them to the target machine?"**

---

I already tried to use this files as a payload for the msi and then use custom action in msi to copy them from Cache Folder

```
 <MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile="$(var.RESOURCES)\Foo.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" DisplayName="Foo">
        <Payload SourceFile="$(var.THIRDPAPTYRESOURCES)\AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" Name="AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" Id="MSADE64"/>
        <Payload SourceFile="$(var.THIRDPAPTYRESOURCES)\AccessDatabaseEngine.exe" Id="MSADE"/>
        <MsiProperty Name="CACHE" Value="[WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
```

But I cant get the value of WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder built-in variable to pass it to msi.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder` was added in WiX 3.9.